# Does Caliburn provide a way to get a reference to the container from anywhere?

Tags: wpf, frameworks, containers, caliburn

I'm currently messing around with Rob Eisenberg's Caliburn framework. When looking at the documentation that is provided on http://caliburn.codeplex.com there is an example of how to resolve a Caliburn service from the container.

It's something along the lines of this:

```
SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();

CaliburnFramework
            .ConfigureCore(container)
            .WithCommonDialogs()
            .WithPresentationFramework()
            .Start();

var service = container.GetInstance(typeof (IService)) as Service;
```

However what I am missing is a way to get a reference to the container anywhere in the app. Like this:

```
var service = Caliburn.Container.GetInstance(typeof(IService))as Service;
```

Do I have to build a custom static class that holds a reference to the container or is there something already built into Caliburn?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest trunk version of Caliburn automatically registers the container on framework startup as an service locator.  You just have to reference `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation` on your code and then ask the `ServiceLocator` for a instance of your service.

```
var service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IService>();
```

Hope that helps.